# Spherical transparent node turns to Cube when colorRamp node is added

Tags: node-editor

I have these nodes set up, and I get a foggy spherical shape which is grey colour. I wanted to change the colour and make it blue, but once I add the colorRamp, the sphere turns into a cube.

PS: I'm following this tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TbrbF38_wUg&t=33s
at 15:04 is where the instructor sets up the node configuration.

Setting up a colour for the Atmospheric sphere is something I'd like to add.

[image: s]

Comment: You may have your color ramp going the wrong way, or there may be an alpha channel in the original gradient texture that you didn’t know about.

Comment: Gradient should be set to Density ...

Comment: I dont see Density in the Gradient settings.

Comment: Sorry for english,  ... Gradient's Color output should be connected to Density input of Volume Scatter node ... Just recheck tutorial node tree.